# Nested try/catch blocks for error propagation across classes?

Tags: c++, error-handling, try-catch

I have a class interface function which implements other functions within the class in a specific order:

```
class Child
{
 public:
      auto Interface()->bool
      {
         this->F1(); //I use this just for extra clarity (e.g. not calling global function)
         this->F2();
         return true;
       }
       auto F1()->void
       {
          //Do stuff...
       }
       auto F2()->void
       {
          //Do more stuff...
       }
};

class Parent
{
  public:
     Child ChildObj;
     auto CallUponChild()->void
     {
            bool success = ChildObj.Interface();
     }
};
```

I want to wrap the 'Interface()' implementation in a try/catch block:

```
auto Interface()->bool
{
  try{
    this->F1();
    this->F2();
  }catch(...){
     //Handle
  }
}
```

However, on the occurance of an error, I wish to attempt the function again, and if that errors, I want to propogate the error back to the Parent class:

```
auto Interface()->bool
{
   int error_count=0;
   try{
      try{
        this->F1();
        this->F2();
        return true;
      }catch(...){
        if(error_count<1){this->F1(); this->F2();}
        else{throw "Out of tries";}
      }
    }catch(...){
       return false;
    }
 }
```

Is using nested try/catch blocks fround upon? Is this the best approach to take?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like

```
auto Interface()->bool
{ int error_count=0;
  while (error_count < 1) {
    try {
      this->F1();
      this->F2();
      return true;
    }
    catch(...){
      // if (error_count >= 1)
      //   throw; // to throw original exception
      ++error_count;
    }
  };
  // throw "Out of tries"; // to throw "Out of tries" exception
  return false; // to use the boolean result
}
```

should be sufficient. If `F1()` throws an exception in your catch block, your function will return `false` without incrementing `error_count`.

Answer (score 1):

It does not seems to be something that the child should handle imho, should that behaviour been handled by the Parent which knows how to deal with their childs? I would go this way:

```
auto CallUponChild()->void
{
    const bool success = ChildObj.Interface();
    if (!success) { // maybe if-init if you have a c++17 compiler
        // try again
        ChildObj.Interface();
    }   
}
```

I think the way to handle the child objects should be at Parent level as I said, Child object should do one thing and if it's needed to be done twice(or N) then should'n be their responsibility.

If you want to show how the exception were thrown you can have a look at this:

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/throw_with_nested